# Remove text from string using string to find text?

Tags: c#, string

I have searched up how to do this. All I got was removing text based on a index point. I would like to have it setup where it uses a string to remove text, instead of choosing the point.

Something along the lines of

```
string text1 = "Hello World!";
string text2 = "Hello";
string text3;

void RemoveText()
{
   text3 = text1.Remove(text2);
   Console.WriteLine(text3);
}
```

Output:

```
 Console: World!
```

Is there a method that can remove text by using a string? I was looking at the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-5.0), but the problem is that the string wouldn't have a denfinite spot that need to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to get part of a user inputed responce, you would doing something along the lines of

```
string textToRemove = "set background ";
Console.WriteLine("Type 'set background ' then your color.");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string answer = userInput.Replace(textToRemove, string.empty);
SetBackgroundColor(answer);
```

First what you want to do is set the text you don't care about/need

```
string textToRemove = "set background ";
```

Next you are going to tell the user what to input and get the input

```
Console.WriteLine("Type 'set background ' then your color.");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

We would then have to make a new string without the unnessary text

```
string answer = userInput.Replace(textToRemove, string.empty);
```

In this case we are using the input to set the background color. So we would write a function for changing the background color with a string argument for the color the user gave.

```
SetBackgroundColor(answer);
```

You could also use an **If statment** or an **for/foreach statment** to see if the user's text without the unneccasry text is in an array or list containing strings that are allowed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
text3 = text1.Replace(text2,string.empty);
```